# How to generate constructors in swagger codegen?

Tags: java, swagger-codegen

The codegen did not generate any constructor.
I referred to petstore swagger file, used latest swagger codegen jar file.

But only default constructor was generated.

It is not generating constructor based on its fields.

How to enable it?

Comment: Which exactly target did you generate? How does the generated constructor look like, and how do you expect it to look like?

Comment: To enable it you will need to modify the template to create the constructors you want

Comment: Swagger generates something different than a typical constructor. It uses builder design pattern. Eg. if you have class `Car` with `engine` and `wheels` variables, you can initialize that class like that: `Car car = new Car().engine("Diesel").wheels(4)`.

Comment: @Defozo How do you enable this builder?

Comment: @Yeikel Maybe you'll be interested in Swagger-codegen Maven/Gradle plugin?

Comment: @defozo I tried the plugin , but I did not find any information about builder generation. Could you please point me to an example?

Answer (score 8):

If you really need a constructor with parameters you can do so by modifying the template file(s) that end with .moustache.

["enable/use/modify" templates](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#modifying-the-client-library-format)

I'm going to assume you're going to be editing an existing template and want a constructor for each model.

Here is a simple example of a constructor inside the model template file:

```
public {{classname}}( {{#vars}} {{datatype}} {{baseName}}{{^-last}},{{/-last}} {{#-last}}){
construct code here
}{{/-last}}{{/vars}}
```

note that this should go between the {{#model}} {{/model}} tags

for more information about the moustache templates refer to

https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html

[List of template variables](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/wiki/Mustache-Template-Variables)

[template examples for the codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/resources)

Comment: Will this approach work to generate constructors that are part of a generated class hierarchy? So if Animal.java has a String name, and Dog.java extends Animal and adds String breed, can this approach generate Dog's constructor like this: Dog(String name, String breed) { super(name); this.breed = breed }?

Comment: There's supposed to be hierarchy/inheritance support in the codegen. I can't guarantee it as I haven't used it yet. I would guess that there are a few hierarchy related codgenmodel variables you can use in the templates(if they work correctly).

Answer (score 1):

I would first like to thank @Viktor Baert for his answer. While the answer provided direction it didn't provide enough to solve it. Note a change and an addition to the answer above.

The change is from *{{datatype}}* to *{{{datatypeWithEnum}}}* in the the constructor signature. This change will support any properties that use generics e.g List.

The second is the inclusion of the assignment of the parameters to the local variables.

When these changes are applied to pojo.mustache either directly or overriding the result is the generation of a usable constructor. This works with both the swagger and openapi generators.

```
public {{classname}}( {{#vars}} {{{datatypeWithEnum}}} {{baseName}}{{^-last}},{{/-last}} {{#-last}}){
  {{#vars}}
  this.{{baseName}} = {{baseName}};
  {{/vars}}
}{{/-last}}{{/vars}}
```

Reference:[add constructors to code generated by openapi codegen](https://www.tomred.net/java/java-add-constructors-to-code-generated-by-openapi-codegen.html)