# Swagger constructor based mandatory fields

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

When I use Swagger-codegen, The only constructor generated is the default constructor. 
I want a constructor with all my fields, for example:

```
public Person(String name, int age) { };
```

Do you know what I should change in the yaml file to make it work? Is it possible? How?

Update - Example:

```
---
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: 1.0.0

paths: {}

definitions:
  Person:
    type: object
    required:
      - name
      - state
    properties:
      name:
         type: string
      state:
         type: string
```

Comment: Can you add a sample Swagger spec so that others can reproduce the behavior? Are the fields defined as required or optional?

Comment: I want a constructor with the 'name' and 'state' fields, no only default constructor

Comment: See my awnser at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45768194/how-to-generate-constructors-in-swagger-codegen