# How to generate copy constructor in Java with Swagger codegen

Tags: java, yaml, swagger, swagger-codegen

The main question relies to how to generate a constructor in Swagger codegen (yaml)?

For example Lets say I want to construct a class named Cat. This will look like this in yaml swagger definitions:

```
Cat:
 type: object
 properties:
   name: string
   color: string
```

And it's class would be like

```
public class Cat {
 String name;
 String color;

 public void Cat() {}

 public void Cat(String name, String colour) {
  this.name = name;
  this.color= color;
 }
}
```

I want to generate also a constructor like

```
public Cat(Cat cat) {
this.name = cat.getName();
this.color = cat.getColor();
}
```

Would be possible?

Thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate constructors in swagger codegen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45768194/how-to-generate-constructors-in-swagger-codegen)

Comment: Saw the page but no information there. Not specified in YAML codegen and no possible answers unfortunately.